# Integration by substituation - wrong integration borders?

Tags: integration

My lecture notes say that for the Chebychev polynomials
$$T_n(x) = \cos(n \arccos x)$$

with a weight function

$$w(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

these integrals are equal:

$$\int_{-1}^{+1} T_n(x)T_m(x)w(x) \mathrm dx = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \cos(n \varphi) \cos(m \varphi) \mathrm d \varphi$$

with the substitution $x = \cos \varphi.$

I don't understand the integration borders $[-\pi, +\pi]$ though. My substitution process so far is:

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{+1} T_n(x)T_m(x)w(x) \mathrm dx &= - \int_{-\arccos(-1)}^{+\arccos(+1)} \frac{\cos(n \varphi) \cos(m \varphi) \sin(\varphi)}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\varphi)}} \mathrm d \varphi \\
&= \int_{0}^{-\pi} \cos(n \varphi) \cos(m \varphi) \mathrm d \varphi
\end{align}

with $x = \cos \varphi \Rightarrow \varphi = \arccos(x)$, $\mathrm d x =  - \sin \varphi$. So I get only half of the integral. Now I don't know whether I made a mistake or the lecture notes are wrong.

Comment: @DuncanH: Actually $\cos(\pm \pi)=-1$...

Comment: I evaluated $\arccos(-1) = \pi$. The $0$ comes from $\arccos(1)$, because $\cos(0) = 1$.

Comment: Uh oh very stupid mistake on my part... @HansLundmark

Comment: @DuncanH: It can happen to anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, and the lecture notes are wrong. For example,

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \cos^2(2\arccos(x))\ dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

([see Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(cos(2%20arccos(x)))(cos(2%20arccos(x)))%2Fsqrt(1-x%5E2)%20from%20-1%20to%201)), while

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2(2\varphi)\ d\varphi = \pi$$

([again, see W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20from%20-pi%20to%20pi%20cos(4x)cos(4x)%20dx)). Note that $\cos(x)$ is an even function, so $\cos(nx)$ is even for any $n$, so the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ of the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Also note that, if $m\neq n$, the integral (from $0$ to $\pi$)

$$\frac{m\sin(\pi m)\cos(\pi n)-n\sin(\pi n)\cos(\pi m)}{m^2-n^2} = 0$$

as $\sin(\pi m) = \sin(\pi n) = 0$. (This evaluation can be proven by using the product-to-sum formulas to reduce the integral to a couple integrals of cosines). Only when $m=n$ will this not be valid (i.e. it will result in $\frac{0}{0}$) and the integral will assume a nonzero value.